# Errors when building unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors, unity-webgl

When I press build in unity (using WebGL) it gives me 3 errors: (I have no other errors/warnings)

1.Internal build system error. read the full binlog without getting a BuildFinishedMessage, while the backend process is still running

2.Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

3.Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 11 seconds (10849 ms) 3 errors UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
[Errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1YXg.png)

I expected unity to build my game.

Comment: There are compile errors in one or more scripts. Look in the editor.log file to see what is failing.

Comment: you need to look in the details of these errors, but the log files Retired Ninja suggested will possibly hold even more info - you havent said if this is a blank project, or a game in progress, which OS, or which version of unity..

Comment: Could this be related to Windows updates? https://forum.unity.com/threads/internal-build-system-error-backend-exited-with-code-after-upgrade-to-2021-1-4f1-stable.1098451/#post-8208414

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without more detail.

When working with WebGL, there's always a few tactics to get myself through MOST issues:

Going through ALL player settings and be as liberal as possible w bug reporting.
Dev mode enabled, throw and support ALL exceptions possible, etc.

Then sanity checks like "Can it build on my desktop?" (Being Windows or Mac). Now if you can't even get it to build on your local machine according to it's OS, then you REALLY have problems.

Another thing is, have you installed any packages/tools/assets? Make a completely blank and brand new and EMPTY project and then try to build to WebGL. Then slowly re-add projects.

The Unity Team does an AMAZING job at making sure assets on the asset store are robust and bug free, but also make sure that anything you get (aside from art) and download SAYS it supports WebGL.

Good luck! I'll follow this and get back to you if you update this post. But without further info helping you is difficult, hence your downvotes.